# Non-hacky solution for runtime created traits can't be displayed in View

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, enthought, mayavi, traitsui

Repeatedly I find myself in this situation,

```
class MainDisplay(HasTraits):
    a=Instance(A,())    
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=A()
    traits_view=View(...)

class A(HasTraits):
    i=Int()
    j=Int()
    k=Int()
    def __init__(self):
        i,j,k=something
    a_display=Group('i','j','k')
```

Problem: I want to display a.i,a.j,a.k in my main display.

Constraints:

(1) i,j,k absolutely must remain members of A and not MainDisplay. It just makes *no sense* to include them in MainDisplay and if I did that for every trait, MainDisplay would become far too cluttered.

(2) MainDisplay must not *inherit* class A. If it did, I could do "Include('a_display')" within traits_view. This is a nice trick for compartmentalizing some of the code from MainDisplay, but it will not work in my case.

(3) MainDisplay must not simply replicate the traits in A, and then sync them. For example MainDisplay.dummy_i=Int(), then later in init, self.sync_traits('dummy_i',self.a,'i',mutual=True). Lastly use 'dummy_i' in MainDisplay.traits_view. This works as well, but again the MainDisplay class becomes so cluttered! Also, every time I want to change the GUI (or a trait), I have two places to edit, which slows down development.

I'm new to GUI's, but I feel like not being able to variables created at runtime is a strange and awkward restriction. My impression is that Enaml, which looks to replace traitsUI also has this restriction.

My main interest is displaying and interacting with 3D geometries created by Mayavi. Is it possible maybe PyQt doesn't have this restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within MainDisplay's view, you can refer to `Item("object.a.i")`, etc, where `object` is literally what you type (not a placeholder). This is described in the TraitsUI documentation's "Advanced View Concepts", section [Multi-Object Views](http://docs.enthought.com/traitsui/traitsui_user_manual/advanced_view.html#multi-object-views).

Comment: Fascinating. Thanks for the help. I'm sure I can make use of this in some cases, but I'm not altogether out of the woods. For example, if a.i is actually a range trait with high and low given by int traits also on a, say a.ceil_i,a.floor_i, then MainDisplay will complain that it is missing ceil_i, floor_i

Comment: Problem 2: This trick will not work if you try it on the member's group of traits instead of each trait individually. e.g. Item('object.a.a_group'). My guess is that if I never call a.configure_traits() that a_group never exists.

Comment: Not sure about your range example. For your second, to display a View within a View, use Instance(...)

Comment: Johnathan, I don't quite understand how to use Instance here. I've tried all of the ways I could think of. Maybe I have a typo. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: Example here: https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/master/examples/demo/Standard_Editors/InstanceEditor_demo.py

Comment: Certainly that is a neat trick. I like it a lot. However I that differs from this example in two small ways. I think I can live with these, but I would like to make sure there's not something I'm missing. (1) I would be forced to rename 'a_display' into 'view' or 'traits_view' or something. This also I think implies that I can not incorporate more than one group from the same class. Say A inherits from A_parent. I would not be able to include both 'a_display' and 'a_parent_display' this way. (2) The resultant gui is a "popout" style. I would I think prefer to have everything in one window.

Comment: answer to (2) is to use style = 'custom'

Comment: Re (1) Yes you need a View, though it doesn't matter what you name it. I'm not aware of any way out of the box to specify different views for the same class, though I'm pretty sure that it could be done with a lot of work (defining a new editor). Generally a cleaner approach would be for each grouping that you want to treat as a unit to be specified as a distinct HasTraits subclass.